# How to display clicked image from a set of images from a linear layout?

Tags: android

i got images from SD card folder and added them to LinearLayout dynamically which is inside a HorizontalScrollview.now when i click an image i want to show that particular image in another ImageView in the same activity as big image. how can i do that? i tried by getting getId(),getTag() but i am unable to do, please give me suggestions. 
Note:I dont want use gallery widget because of center-locking feature.
My code :

```
    package com.pop.cam;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class GalleryView extends Activity {

        ImageView iv;
        File[] sdDirFiles;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        int i;
        String path;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.pictures);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearView);
            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

            // getting images from SD card folder
            File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/"
                    + MyCameraAppActivity.DIR_NAME);
            sdDirFiles = sdDir.listFiles();
            for (i = 0; i < sdDirFiles.length; i++) {
                final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, 100));
                Bitmap b = decodeFile(sdDirFiles[i].getAbsoluteFile());
                imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
                path = sdDirFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Here i want to set clicked image as big.
                                        //I tried following but not workin
                        iv.setImageResource(v.getId());
                                        iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
Bitmap b = decodeFile(sdDirFiles[Integer.valueOf(v.getId())].getAbsoluteFile());
                    iv.setImageBitmap(b);

                    }
                });
                linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            }
        }

        // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
            try {
                // Decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

                // The new size we want to scale to
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

                // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                int scale = 1;
                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                        && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    scale *= 2;

                // Decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

pictures.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScorllView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line before `imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

```
imageView.setId(i);
```

Use below lines in place of `iv.setImageResource(v.getId());`

```
int id = v.getId();
Bitmap b = decodeFile(sdDirFiles[id].getAbsoluteFile()); // this gives small image bcoz you implemented decodeFile like that.
iv.setImageBitmap(b);
```

**or**

```
int id = v.getId();                 
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sdDirFiles[id].getAbsoluteFile()); // it will produce original resolution or fit to screen
iv.setImageURI(uri);
```

I tested this code, its working fine.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Yugandhar i tried with that its giving following error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: index=-1 length=15

Comment: @Yugander, Problem is that i need to get clicked image id since i am using for loop for small image view's creation, i am getting -1.even i used iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sdDirFiles[i].getAbsolutePath())); which gives last image.

Comment: @Yugander its force closing the app since id is -1

Comment: @PSrinivasgoud i am using with 16 images, its working fine. no such error or id value -1 for me. how you are getting this error. You forgot to add **setId()**. First read my answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. you need to toggle the visibility of your `ImageView` so that it will work like an overlay. Make it visible if you touched one of your images and turn it off if you touch your big `ImageView` (just a sample behavior...)
2. Use the `setTag()` method to store the ID, in your case the variable `i` in the small `ImageView`. In your `onClick` method, you get the tag by `getTag()` and than use it to load the image with the ID `i` from the `sdDirFiles` list.

that should be all you need.

Sample code (read the comments!):

```
    for (i = 0; i < sdDirFiles.length; i++) {
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(130, 100));
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(sdDirFiles[i].getAbsoluteFile());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        imageView.setTag(i); // SET THE TAG!
        path = sdDirFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // set the big imageview with the clicked image
                Bitmap b = decodeFile(sdDirFiles[Integer.valueOf(v.getId())].getAbsoluteFile());
                iv.setImageBitmap(b);
            }
        });
        linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: @WarrenFath Thanks for reply. i tried this but Tag giving null can u please give sample code for this.

Comment: @WarrenFath Problem is that i need to get clicked image id since i am using for loop for small image view's creation, i am getting -1.even i used iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(sdDirFiles[i].getAbsolutePath())); which gives last image.

Comment: Added code sample, please read the two comments to get the idea!

Comment: i tried with sample code not working as i said ID coming as -1

Comment: `Not working` isn't a good problem description. What exactly is the problem with using the tag value? The side effect of missusing the id can be problematic in some cases...